# Diagonalization:Algebraic and Geometric multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

How could I prove that if the geometric multiplicity of all eigen values of a matrix equals its algebraic multiplicity, then the matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: You get the proof in any standard linear algebra books.

Comment: If I had understood it, I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 6):

Well, that's obvious: if the geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues are equal to their algebraic multiplicities, as the sum of the algebraic multiplicities is the dimension $n$ of the vector space, it means we have a set of $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, which are therefore a *basis* of eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you for your help !

Comment: You're welcome!